# PHP warnings with stacktrace

Tags: php

Is it possible to log a stacktrace on warnings?

Here is the way I log all warning and notice errors

```
function boot_error_handler($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline){
    switch($errno){
        case E_WARNING:
        case E_PARSE:
        case E_NOTICE:
            $message = "$errstr $errfile:$errline";
            if(class_exists('Log')){
                Log::write($message, 'warning', true);
            }
            if(ENV != ENV_PROD){
                echo $message;
            }
            break;
    }
}
set_error_handler('boot_error_handler');
```

Comment: You can use `debug_backtrace()` to get current stacktrace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(new \Exception)->getTraceAsString();
```

is an easy way of generating a nicely formatted trace (PHP 5.4+)

It'll just return a string, so you can either replace or extend your existing log messages with it as appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `debug_backtrace()` function in you error handler to get current stacktrace. The thing is that it returns array of associative arrays wichi is uncomfortable to use if you just need to log it, because you would need to generate a human-readable string form it.

Another solution would be to create an `Exception` instance and use its method `getTraceAsString()`.

```
$exception = new \Exception();
$trace = $exception->getTraceAsString();
```

So basically it depends if the default exsceptions stacktrace format is enough for you or you want to have soem custom format.

Answer (score 1):

Use [debug_backtrace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php) or fire an exception, catch it and get its trace with getTraceAsString():

```
try {
    throw new Exception();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    $e->getTraceAsString();
}
```